# Why does dev-container launch flask app listening on two different ports

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, flask

I have a flask app running in a devcontainer in VSCode.  I have a mapping in the docker compose to map 5050 to 5000, the default port that flask listens on.  When i run the app, i can access my site from localhost:5050, but also from localhost:5001.  I can not for the life of me figure out where the port mapping for 5001 is coming from?
Has anyone else experience something similar?

This is what my docker compose looks like:

version: '3.8'

```
services:
  web_app:
    container_name: web_app
    image: web_app
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces:cached
    command: sleep infinity
    network_mode: service:db


  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports: 
      - 5050:5000

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

And the devcontainer.json:

```
{
    "name": "web_app",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "web_app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/postgres-asdf:1": {
            "version": "latest"
        }
    }
```

and finally the launch.json for flask:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Flask",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "flask",
    "env": {
        "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceFolder:alpha_insite_app}/src/web/app.py",
        "FLASK_ENV": "development",
        "FLASK_DEBUG": "1" 
    },
    "args": [
        "run",
        "--no-debugger",
        "--host", "0.0.0.0"
    ],
    "jinja": true,
    "justMyCode": true,
    "console": "integratedTerminal",

},
```

Comment: Does this only happen in vscode? You can run the command `netstat -tlnp | grep :5001` to display a list of all programs listening on port 5001. Also check whether the configuration of the flask application has a reference to port 5001.